# Joining equal length tables with no common Keys, n-th row with n-th row

Tags: t-sql, join

It seems so simple but i can't find a nice way to do it:
I have to tables, each with a single column, containing a number.
I  need a table with two columns, the first one is the column of the first table, the second is the column of the second table.
I want the first row to be made by the values of the first (single cell) rows of the two starting columns.
The two tables have no Primary Keys , i can't add a primary key and they are the result of a function.

Is there a smart way to do this?

I can't find the same question around sry.

Comment: Sample data and a desired result?! Since tables have no implicit ordering, do you want to order both by the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people will probably use some kind of windows function like ROW_NUMBER() but that will sort your values before assigning the "Primary Key". Try this out instead:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Value INT
)

CREATE TABLE #table2
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Value INT
)

INSERT INTO #table1(value)
    SELECT col1
    FROM #table1

INSERT INTO #table2(value)
    SELECT col1
    FROM #table2

SELECT  #table1.Value,
        #table2.Value
FROM #table1
INNER JOIN #table2
    ON #table1.ID = #table2.ID
```